# How can I enable one by one an array element(C#) Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code is C# and I'm using the Unity game engine.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CollisionDetectionForQuest : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] Garbages;
public GameObject[] GarbagesDummy;
public bool activateInactive;
//public GameObject[] Counter;


void Start(){

    Garbages = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Trash");
    foreach (GameObject garb in Garbages) {

    }

    GarbagesDummy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("TrashDummy");
    foreach(GameObject dummy in GarbagesDummy){
        dummy.gameObject.SetActive (false); 
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj){
    if (obj.gameObject.CompareTag ("Trash")) {
        obj.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        activateInactive = true;

       //in this line i want to activate my GarbageDummy 1 by 1 base on
       //every Trash i put in my collider.
        foreach(GameObject a in GarbagesDummy){
            a.gameObject.SetActive (true);
        }
}
```

So basically I want to activate the **garbagedummy** gameobject 1 by 1 on every **trash** I put on my collider. But I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
foreach(GameObject dummy in GarbageDummy){
   for(int i = 0; i < GarbageDummy.Length; i++){
     dummy.gameobject.setActive(true);
  }
}
```

anyone help please.

Here is my screenshot:

[image: Here]

Comment: Hmm It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Do you mean each time you put a `trash` object on your collider, you want to activate one `garbage dummy` object? Does it need to be any particular garbage dummy or just any of them?

Comment: @LukeBriggs any of them sir . cause every time i put **trash** object on my collider i'll set it as setActive(false) then activate my **garbage dummy** object so that it will look like i just put it naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to activate a single garbage dummy object (any of them in the array), then you don't want to use a loop there. Instead, keep track of which one you've activated up to as a field like this:

```
public int ActivatedDummyIndex; // Add this!
public GameObject[] Garbages;
public GameObject[] GarbagesDummy;
...
```

Then whenever a trash object is added, increase that number and use it as an index in your GarbagesDummy array:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision obj){
    if (obj.gameObject.CompareTag ("Trash")) {
        obj.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        activateInactive = true;

        // Get the next dummy:
        GameObject dummy = GarbagesDummy[ActivatedDummyIndex];

        // Increase the index for next time:
        ActivatedDummyIndex++;

        // Activate that dummy:
        dummy.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

**This assumes that the number of dummy objects is the same as the number of trash objects.** If you've got more trash objects and add them all, you'll eventually get an index out of range exception (as it would "run out" of dummy objects to use).

Whilst that should answer your question, it's worth mentioning that *this isn't the typical approach*. Rather than having a fixed number of hidden dummy objects and showing one when needed, you'd normally instance a new dummy object instead (using [GameObject.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)).

Comment: Wow nice approach . Thank you very much for you help

Comment: But i have a problem when i tried your suggestion it doesn't activate when i load it . I guess i need this line of code:

        if (obj.gameObject.CompareTag ("TrashDummy")) {
   to activate it when i load my game

Comment: @TheGinxx009 `CompareTag("Trash")` or `CompareTag("TrashDummy")` will depend on which object the above script is actually attached to :)

Comment: so how can i possibly do it sir? Sorry just noob to game development >.<

Comment: @TheGinxx009 what's not activating? When what loads? Do you mean the trash isn't activating when the game loads?

Comment: I mean i do have a **save and load system**. So this line of code:
if (obj.gameObject.CompareTag ("Trash")) {
        obj.gameObject.SetActive (false);
}
it is actually working when i load it . So i don't know what type of condition i should use to save the **dummies**

Comment: @TheGinxx009 Right ok - so the player can save the game and when they load it back you'd like to make sure the dummies are correct? It's best asking that as a separate question so you can add more detail (as the save/load system isn't in/ related to this question) :)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry sir . So how can i possibly do that. Actually i don't need to change or add some code on my saving/loading system cause it automatically detects my gameobjects . the problem is i need the comparetag code because it helps me to locate my prefab object.

Comment: Do you mean the `CompareTag("Trash")` line in your question here? Hmm, I'm really struggling to see how that could relate to a save/ load system. I think it's more a language barrier thing - what's your native language? :)

Comment: Php. 
yeah im struggling also on what condition should i use here
if (obj.gameObject.CompareTag ("Trash")) {
        obj.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        activateInactive = true;

        // Get the next dummy:
        GameObject dummy = GarbagesDummy[ActivatedDummyIndex];

        // Increase the index for next time:
        ActivatedDummyIndex++;
        if(this.gameobject.comparetag("Trashdummy")){
         // Activate that dummy:
        dummy.SetActive(true);
    }
}
i cant do it like this because this doesnt work

Comment: @TheGinxx009 How come you need to "locate" your prefab? Usually a prefab is setup from the inspector (as one of the fields in your script). You should see a prompt to move this to chat shortly - when it does, join in so I can better understand what it is you're trying to achieve :)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation so i edit my answer. @Luke